# Not able to resolve Unix command read from XML

Tags: bash, unix

I am having XML file say app_config.xml. This contains below line:

### app_config.xml

```
<conf>
    <LOGFILENAME>seasonalitylog.$now.log</LOGFILENAME>
</conf>
```

I am reading  in a script file say test.sh

### test.sh

```
file_name=awk -F '</?LOGFILENAME>' $'{print $2}' app_config.xml
```

Tried using eval command :
eval echo `awk -F '</?LOGFILENAME>' '{print $2}' app_config.xml` but it is not returning correct result. It is returning blank.

Please help me to understand where i am hoing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obvious thing that you are doing wrong is trying to parse XML with regular expressions. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454) on why that's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't running that awk command with that line.

You are assigning "awk" to the `file` variable and trying to run the `-F` command.

You need to wrap the awk command in `$(....)`.

```
file_name=$(awk -F '</?LOGFILENAME>' $'{print $2}' app_config.xml)
```

Answer (score 1):

For XML parsing, you may want to use `xpath`:

```
$ xpath -q -e "/conf/LOGFILENAME/text()" app_config.xml
seasonalitylog.$now.log
```

Or in a variable:

```
filename=$(xpath -q -e "/conf/LOGFILENAME/text()" app_config.xml)
```